# Sapui5 xml forceselection set with expresssion evaluation

Tags: sapui5

<Input value="{item>/productVersion/id}"  forceSelection ="{= ${item>/cic/edit} === 'true' ? 'false':'true'} />
i want to set forceselection true or false based on the condition.
also is there any way to make a field mandatory based on a condition in sap ui5

Comment: as long as the control supports the `required` parameter, you can use the same conditional logic in the binding

Answer (score 0):

`'false'` and `'true'` are strings. You want booleans. If `/cic/edit` returns a boolean just use that.

If you want the negated value you can use expression binding

```
forceSelection="{= !${item>/cic/edit} }"
```

Comment: can you help me forceSelection="{= ${item>/type} === 'DataPlane' ? false : true }". this makes force selection true when it is dataplane but it does not make it false when  dataplane(or the condition fails)

Answer (score -1):

I now understand that you can’t set `forceselection` dynamically or based on a condition. It’s SAAP UI5 limitation, it seems.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).